# Load iPhone version of page in WKWebView on iPad?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have a page in my app that displays a `WKWebView`. It looks great on iPhone, but doesn't look so good on iPad.

On iPad, the page is too big and gets cut off, so you have to scroll horizontally. That doesn't look good, and it doesn't work well since this is in a page view controller. I want everything to fit on the page. Is there a way to load the iPhone version of the page, even on iPad? Or is there another solution I can use?

[image: WKWebView on iPhone]

[image: WKWebView on iPhone]

Comment: May be autolayout and size class is what you want i think!

Comment: The webview itself is actually being resized okay. It's just that the content inside it is bigger than the webview's frame so it scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

To load iPhone version of site on iPad, you need to change user agent of your web view. First, you need to find appropriate user agent value. Go to www.whatismyuseragent.net from your iPhone. After that, change `WKWebView` user agent:

```
webView.customUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A366 Safari/600.1.4";
```

Of course, in real world you will only need to replace occurrences of "iPad" with "iPhone" in your user agent. Something like:

```
[webView evaluateJavaScript:@"navigator.userAgent" completionHandler:^(id __nullable userAgent, NSError * __nullable error) {
    webView.customUserAgent = [userAgent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPad" withString:@"iPhone"];
    // Start actual site loading.
}
```

Obviously, you need to do that before loading actual web page.

Comment: I have actually tried that since I posted this, and it didn't make any difference.